# Downloading a RAR file from Mediafire using WGET

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, script, wget

Example: `http://www.mediafire.com/?tjmjrmtuyco`

This was what I tried...

```
wget -A rar [-r [-l 1]] <mediafireurl>
```

That is to say, I tried with and without the recursive option. It ends up downloading an HTML page of a few KB in size, while what I want is in the range 90-100 MB and RAR.

What happens with MediaFire for those who may not be aware, is that it first says

Processing Download Request...

This text after a second or so turns into the download link and reads

Click here to start download..

I would appreciate it if someone would tell me how to write a proper script for this situation.

Comment: This is probably not allowed according to [the Mediafire TOS](http://www.mediafire.com/terms_of_service.php) and they will do their best to make it as hard as possible for you to do.

Comment: seems to be difficult with captcha, javascript timer and all the other things in place...
they also have mechanisms in place to block downloads from much more sophisticated download managers..

Comment: you can try jdownloader.
it automates the download process from such file sharing sites(mediafire, filesonic etc.)

Answer (score 6):

From [Mediafires Terms of Service](http://www.mediafire.com/policies/terms_of_service.php):

> ### General Use of the Service, Permissions and Restrictions
>
> You agree while using MediaFire Services, that you may not:
>
> Alter or modify any part of the Services;
>
> Use the Services for any illegal purpose;
>
> Use any robot, spider, offline readers, site search and/or retrieval
> application, or other device to retrieve or index any portion of the
> Services, with the exception of public search engines

So essentially by using anything other than the tools that Mediafire provide via their website you are in fact breaking their terms of service.

Comment: But if `wget` counts as a "retrieval application" then a browser does too... I think they're talking about things that crawl the whole site

Answer (score 5):

Actually it can be done.  What you have to do is:

- Go to the link like you're going to download to your computer
- When the "download" button comes up, "right-click" and copy the link and add that to your `wget`.

It'll be something like

```
wget http://download85794.mediafire.com/whatever_your_file_is
```

Comment: That's right! it works this way

Comment: Does not work anymore sadly, they just serve the .html

Answer (score 5):

bash function:

```
mdl () {
url=$(curl -Lqs "$1"|grep "href.*download.*media.*"|tail -1|cut -d '"' -f 2)
aria2c -x 6 "$url" # or wget "$url" if you prefer.
}
```

> Example:
>   $ sudo apt install aria2
>   $ mdl "http://www.mediafire.com/?tjmjrmtuyco"
>
> 01/14 13:58:34 [NOTICE] Downloading 1 item(s)
>   38MiB/100MiB(38%) CN:4 DL:6.6MiB ETA:9s]

Answer (score 4):

I've never tried myself, but there are a few things you could try to "cheat" the website.

For example `--referer` will let you specify a referer URL - maybe the site expects you to come from a specific "home" page or something: with this option wget will pretend it's coming from there.

Also, `--user-agent` will make wget "pretend" it's a different agent - namely, a browser like Firefox.

`--header` will let you forge the whole HTTP request to mimic that of a browser.

If none of those work, there are also more options, dealing with cookies and other advanced settings: `man wget` for the whole list.

I hope this helps a bit: if you succeed, please post how you did it!

Answer (score 4):

Mediafire now allows to download from the IP you have requested. So 1st you need to download the page using following command

```
curl -O "http://www.mediafire.com/file/6ddhdfg/db.zip/file"
```

Once the file is downloaded, find the URL inside the file like

```
http://download*.mediafire.com/*
```

and then use the command wget to download the file

```
wget http://download*.mediafire.com/*
```

P.S. * varies downloads to downloads. so you need to find that exact value.

Answer (score 2):

Sites like this use multiple methods to prevent simple/automated downloading. A few examples of such techniques include:

- Using sessions
- Generating unique download links/keys
- Using CAPTCHAS (*can* be defeated, but certainly not by wget)
- Timers for non-premium users to delay the download
- IFrames containing the download link
- Providing the link from another site/domain
- Checking the web client (is it a web browser or something else)
- Checking referer to prevent hotlinking (did the download request come from the site or elsewhere)
- Checking the headers to verify it conforms to their expectations
- Using PUT instead of GET to use "hidden" form fields
- Setting and checking cookies
- Using JavaScript to redirect or generate the download link
- Using Flash to test the user or generate the download link

Basically, downloading files from sites like this with tools like cURL or wget would at best, be difficult, and certainly not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the download button, "copy link address"

> wget (url)

Easy as that, just did it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other anwsers dont seem to work anymore. But ive found another trick that did work for me.

Using chrome as a example, but this should work on all chromium-based browsers:

Open f12 and go to the network tab
click the download button.
find the newly downloading file in the network tab and while that's downloading rightclick it, go to copy and then copy as curl (bash). If you do this while the download is active on your browser and execute this on the commandline (in this case the bash shell) then it will download correctly.

You should pipe this output to a file with `curl x > outputfile` so you don't everything thrown at your terminal session but instead save to a file.